# RXJava Async help needed. input blocked by call

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-android

I have the below code that works well with displaying results in a list view. The problem is that the call blocks the keyboard when typing, but when I try to subscribe on the io thread it doesnt work.  My question is: Where is the correct place to make a call to my rest interface?

```
o1 = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(etSearch).throttleLast(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(new Func1<RxTextViewTextChangeEvent, String>() {
                     @Override
                     public String call(RxTextViewTextChangeEvent rxTextViewTextChangeEvent) {
                         return etSearch.getText().toString();
                     }
                 }
            );
    o1.observeOn(RxAndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(String s) {
            return s.length() > 2;
        }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(String s) {

                List<CrewMember> crewMemberList = rest.getCrewMemberList(s);
                ListView crewFinderResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                crewMemberAdapter = new CrewFinderResultRowAdapter(mContext, getLayoutInflater());
                crewMemberAdapter.setCrewMemberList(crewMemberList);
                crewFinderResultsListView.setAdapter(crewMemberAdapter);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `rest.getCrewMemberList(s)` is a network call or otherwise kind of blocking call that holds back the main thread. If the first, you're probably getting a network on main thread exception which gets swallowed because you don't use the `subscribe` overload with an error callback. You have to move the call to the io() scheduler:

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(etSearch)
    .throttleLast(500, SECONDS)
    .filter(s -> s.length() > 2)
    .switchMap(s -> 
        Observable.fromCallable(() -> rest.getCrewMemberList(s))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(crewMembersList -> {
        ListView crewFinderResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            crewMemberAdapter = new CrewFinderResultRowAdapter(
                mContext, getLayoutInflater());
            crewMemberAdapter.setCrewMemberList(crewMemberList);
            crewFinderResultsListView.setAdapter(crewMemberAdapter);
    },
    e -> Log.d(...));
```

Comment: Still trying to get mine to work but I understand what your suggesting and it seems like the way to go. Thanks for your help!